# JQuery Query... DatePicker re-opening in Browsers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, browser, datepicker

I have a browser compatibility problem I think.  I am using a RAD environment so I know it takes a little work putting all the various elements in the right place.  Anyway I have added a Jquery UI datepicker to a form.

The following jquery code works fine in Firefox and Chrome, the datepicker works as expected and is reusable (clicking away and back onto it allows it pop up).  The code is placed on the on-click event of a date field:

```
 $('#datePicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
 });
```

Unfortunately it does not work in I.E.  However if I slightly edit the code to:

```
datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
```

});

It works in I.E. but not Firefox / Chrome.

I am very very new to JQuery / Javascript and I am wondering if I am doing wrong (or is this a browser problem I just have to come to terms with).

Thanks in advance.

n34panda

Edit 2 -> I believe this is not a browser incompatability issue, the code is fine:

```
 $('#datePicker').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
 });
```

Comment: I'm not sure to see any difference between code working on IE and the one which doesn't work... Now what error do you get in IE console, if any?

Comment: Your right, I've narrowed the problem down. We have an expandable/collapsible panel on the same page and if the user uses the date picker first it works 100% reopening etc as expected.  However if they move to the map and expand/collapse it then return to the datepicker it doesn't work.  I assume we have some jquery conflict somewhere - probably in the code I have just added to my first post

Comment: Could you set a jsfiddle which replicates your issue? I don't see what could be the issue on IE. BTW, which IE and jQuery version are you testing it?

Comment: just spent 10 minutes making a jsfiddle and then tested it on all browsers without any problem.  I then go back and test my page again and it works...god damn!  Anyway - storing a copy for safe keeping and moving on.  Thanks for your help...I imagine it was just me and this wasn't a "problem" after all.

Comment: So that's a good news ;)